# Azure Python SDK storage backup fails

Tags: azure, azure-python-sdk

I am facing a problem in my script and honestly I don't know anymore where to look and/or how to solve it.

I have the following script.

```
# Source Client
connection_string = '' # The connection string for the source container
account_key = '' # The account key for the source container

# source_container_name = 'newblob' # Name of container which has blob to be copied
table_service_out = TableService(account_name='', account_key='')
table_service_in = TableService(account_name='', account_key='')

# Create client
client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string) 




client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
all_containers = client.list_containers(include_metadata=True)
for container in all_containers:
    # Create sas token for blob
    sas_token = generate_account_sas(
        account_name = client.account_name,
        account_key = account_key, 
        resource_types = ResourceTypes(object=True, container=True),
        permission= AccountSasPermissions(read=True,list=True),
        # start = datetime.now(),
        expiry = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=24) # Token valid for 4 hours
    )

    
    print("==========================")
    print(container['name'], container['metadata'])
    
    # print("==========================")
    container_client = client.get_container_client(container.name)
    # print(container_client)
    blobs_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    for blob in blobs_list:
        # Create blob client for source blob
        source_blob = BlobClient(
        client.url,
        container_name = container['name'],
        blob_name = blob.name,
        credential = sas_token
    )
        target_connection_string = ''
        target_account_key = ''
        source_container_name = container['name']
        target_blob_name = blob.name
        target_destination_blob = container['name'] + today
        print(target_blob_name)
        # print(blob.name)
        target_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(target_connection_string)
        container_client = target_client.get_container_client(target_destination_blob)
        if not container_client.exists():
            container_client.create_container()
        new_blob = target_client.get_blob_client(target_destination_blob, target_blob_name)
        new_blob.start_copy_from_url(source_blob.url)
        print("COPY TO: " + target_connection_string)
        print(f"TRY: saving blob {target_blob_name} into {target_destination_blob} ")
        # except:
        #     # Create new blob and start copy operation.
        #     new_blob = target_client.get_blob_client(target_destination_blob, target_blob_name)
        #     new_blob.start_copy_from_url(source_blob.url)
        #     print("COPY TO: " + target_connection_string)
        #     print(f"EXCEPT: saving blob {target_blob_name} into {target_destination_blob} ")
        

#query 100 items per request, in case of consuming too much menory load all data in one time
query_size = 1000

#save data to storage2 and check if there is lefted data in current table，if yes recurrence
#save data to storage2 and check if there is lefted data in current table，if yes recurrence
def queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(source_table_name, target_table_name,resp_data:ListGenerator ,table_out:TableService,table_in:TableService,query_size:int):
    for item in resp_data:
        tb_name = source_table_name + today
        #remove etag and Timestamp appended by table service
        del item.etag
        del item.Timestamp
        print("INSERT data:" + str(item) + "into TABLE:"+ tb_name)
        table_in.insert_or_replace_entity(target_table_name,item)
    if resp_data.next_marker:
        data = table_out.query_entities(table_name=source_table_name,num_results=query_size,marker=resp_data.next_marker)
        queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(source_table_name, target_table_name, data,table_out,table_in,query_size)


tbs_out = table_service_out.list_tables()
print(tbs_out)

for tb in tbs_out:
    table = tb.name + today
    #create table with same name in storage2
    table_service_in.create_table(table_name=table, fail_on_exist=False)

    #first query
    data = table_service_out.query_entities(tb.name,num_results=query_size)
    queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(tb.name, table,data,table_service_out,table_service_in,query_size)
```

This works just fine as it copies all the blobs and table from a source storage and paste them into a destination storage. But the problem that I am facing is when the source storage account containers contains a blob that has `$web` if that exist, my script throws an error `The Resource contains an invalid character` which is weird as I checked the container and its content files, and they all have allowed characters.

Am I missing something about this configuration or doing something wrong?

Thank you so much for any help you can provide and please if you need more info just let me know

Comment: Where exactly does your code fail?

Comment: It fails at this line `if not container_client.exists():         container_client.create_container()`
and this happens only if I have container `$web`. and the error is this. `azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.` but its confusing because it does not give any error with container `$logs`, both those containers are default for azure and you can create them with that character. I really don't understand

Comment: Generally speaking `$` is an invalid character in a blob container name. However `$root`, `$logs` and `$web` are special blob containers where this check is not performed. I just tried to create a blob container with `$web` name and I was able to do so. 2 things: 1) What's the version of Azure Blobs SDK you're using and 2) What's the kind of target storage account (General Purpose V1/V2 or Blob Storage etc.)? Please edit your question and provide this information.